# How to load trustStore files from HDFS or S3 in YugabyteDB YCQL spark connector?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I want to read data from Yugabyte YCQL using spark application, I'm using  spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.0-yb-8. I want to use encryption at the transit level.

```
"spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabled": "true"
"spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.password": "changeit"
"spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.path": "/usr/local/openjdk-11/lib/security/cacerts"
```

Is there a way to load trustStore file from HDFS or S3 server?

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://github.com/VerdigrisTech/spark-cassandra-connection-factory for S3. Another option is to run a script or `wget` to download the file locally.